# Have two paths with a varying URL in Google Analytics goal funnel

Tags: google, analytics, goals

How do I track which application form generated goals based on a different URL in one step of the goal funnel?

Lets say that there are two ways to fill the form and make the conversion:

1. `/register`
2. `/msignature`
3. `/proceed`
4. `/thankyou`

and another:

1. `/register`
2. `/upload`
3. `/proceed`
4. `/thankyou`

The second step is different in the two cases. I want to see not only the  conversions, but also see how many people chose one or another way to make a conversion.  That way I can measure the effectiveness of each way user can choose.

Comment: Why you only need one goal?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with goals.   GA goal funnels are very limiting.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways you can  solve this.

1. Create unique goals for each url i.e. two separate goals.
2. Keep the single goal, but setup two segments which filter your report based on page url. One segment for each url.

Comment: The thing is (and probably the main problem) I need to create a funnel. I thought I can make event based goal which would act as a one of the step to the main goal however it is not possible (strangely).

Comment: The fact that event based goals can't be funnels and that events can't be used as funnel steps in destination goal funnels is a pretty awful limitation of Google Analytics.

Comment: Well, it is possible to use events as well  if you upgrade to GA 360 but that is something only larger oganizations can afford.

Comment: @Martynas how about funnels based on the different page paths user takes instead of events? Make all url steps mandatory. Would that suit your need?

Comment: @KristianSvensson great answer, can you give a little more detail on how to setup #2? Would the goal include both /msignature and /upload? What would the segment be based on, "Page"?