# Separate conversion goals for separate products in Google Analytics when there is a single "thank you" page

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, products

I have 6 products, each product has separate application form (different url), but "thanks for application" page I have only one for all application forms.

I set up goal with funnel `/product-1-application-form` (required) and `/thanks-for-application` and other goal with funnel `/product-2-application-form` (required) and `/thanks-for-application` but still if someone sent me application, google analytics counts this goal for both products goals.

How should I set up goals that google analytics counts separate goals for product 1 and product 2?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is fairly limited in its flexibility in for goal tracking.  If you have multiple goals, they each need a unique set of URLs, or GA gets the tracking messed up.

The easiest way to implement it is usually to send users to a thank you page with a dummy parameter.  For example:

- `/product-1-application-form` -> `/thanks-for-application?product=1`
- `/product-2-application-form` -> `/thanks-for-application?product=2`

The "product" parameter would have no effect on how the page looks, it would only be used for tracking.  This allows you to re-use the same thank you page multiple times but to vary the thank you page URL for Google Analytics goal tracking.

Here are a couple of similar questions where you can find additional info:

- [Have two paths with a varying URL in Google Analytics goal funnel](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109571/have-two-paths-with-a-varying-url-in-google-analytics-goal-funnel)
- [Google Analytics double count conversions when there are two goal paths to the same final destination](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112458/google-analytics-double-count-conversions-when-there-are-two-goal-paths-to-the-s)